# Partial Match of text in R

Tags: r

I have one data set, which contains ids and their corresponding phrase. One Id can have phrases of 2 or 3 words. Within one Id, if we have phrases of 2 or 3 words, match the phrase of 2 words with 3 words phrase. If matched, retain 2 words phrase and delete 3 words phrase.

```
 Data:
          id         text
          11    XYX not working
          11    cant find anything
          11    wont let go
          11    wont let open
          11    not working
          11    let open
          12    no music store
          12    no sound store
          12    not playing
          12    not printing
          12    no music
          13    paper issue
          13    charger issue
          14    no issue found
```

Example: In id(11) 'let open' matches with 'wont let open'. So delete 'wont let open' and retain 'let open'. 'not working' matches with 'XYX not working', so retain 'not working'. Also retain other phrases which are not matched. Always we need to match the phrases where ever we have 2 and 3 words phrases in particular id.

```
 Expected output:

          id          text
          11    cant find anything
          11    wont let go
          11    not working
          11    let open
          12    no sound store
          12    not playing
          12    not printing
          12    no music
          13    paper issue
          13    charger issue
          14    no issue found
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does word order matter? (Would "wont let go" match with "wont go" or "go let"?)

Comment: @Bishops_Guest : Yes, word order matter. Sequence should be same. "wont let go" should not match with "wont go" or "go let".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `tidyverse` family of packages:

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)

is_long_phrase <- function(x) {
  map_lgl(x, ~ !any(str_detect(.x, setdiff(x, .x))))
}

data %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(is_long_phrase(text)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# the data
df <- read.csv(text='id,text
                 11,XYX not working
                 11,cant find anything
                 11,wont let go
                 11,wont let open
                 11,not working
                 11,let open
                 12,no music store
                 12,no sound store
                 12,not playing
                 12,not printing
                 12,no music
                 13,paper issue
                 13,charger issue
                 14,no issue found', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# the code
df$words <- lapply(strsplit(df$text, split='\\s+'), length) # words in text
df.idlst <- split(df, df$id) 
Vgrepl <- Vectorize(grepl, 'pattern', SIMPLIFY = TRUE)
df$del <- unlist(lapply(df.idlst, function(df) sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) ifelse(df[i,]$words == 3, any(Vgrepl(df[df$words==2,]$text, df[i,]$text)), FALSE))))
df[!df$del,][1:2] # df[row,]$del == TRUE => the row has to be deleted

# the output
   id               text
2  11 cant find anything
3  11        wont let go
5  11        not working
6  11           let open
8  12     no sound store
9  12        not playing
10 12       not printing
11 12           no music
12 13        paper issue
13 13      charger issue
14 14     no issue found
```

Comment: Thanks @sandipan. Your code is working and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to create a custom function and apply it to the data set

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)

fun1 <- function(x){
  if(length(x) > 1) {
    m1 <- expand.grid(x[stri_count_words(x) == 3], x[stri_count_words(x) == 2])
    ind <- unique(m1[apply(m1, 1, function(i)length(Reduce(`intersect`, stri_extract_all_words(i)))) == 2,1])
  }
  return(as.character(ind))
}

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(!text %in% fun1(text))

#Source: local data frame [11 x 2]
#Groups: id [4]

#      id               text
#   <int>              <chr>
#1     11        not working
#2     11           let open
#3     11 cant find anything
#4     11        wont let go
#5     12        not playing
#6     12       not printing
#7     12           no music
#8     12     no sound store
#9     13        paper issue
#10    13      charger issue
#11    14     no issue found
```

Comment: Thanks @Sotos. I am getting error. It says "Error: object 'ind' not found"

Comment: Might be a typo. I ll look at it as soon as I can.